# Dataframe копировать значение взамен предыдущих

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как можно из столбца `df['t']` копировать первое встретившееся значение на все предыдущие нули, затем снова первое встретившиеся значение после нулей копировать на них и т. д.? В данном случае итоговый результат для `df['t']` — это все единицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала замените нули на nan. Затем замените nan на предыдущее значение с помощью fillna и метода "bfill":

```
df['t'] = df['t'].replace(0, pd.NA).fillna(method="bfill")
```